# ActiveX Label Inserted on Worksheet via VBA Displays White Border on Right and Bottom

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I am trying to insert an ActiveX label over a shape on a sheet. Here is the code.

```
    Dim oleObj As OLEObject

        Set oleObj = wireframeSht.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", Link:=False, _
                     DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=282.375, Top:=52.125, Width:=72, Height:= _
                     18)

        oleObj.Object.BackColor = RGB(54, 95, 145)
        oleObj.Object.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
```

The label inserted via the above code displays a white border on its right and bottom whereas a label inserted via Insert menu would not have those borders. (image attached)

[Label image showing the borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOuLS.png)

Is there a way not to get this displayed?

Comment: This is the VBA way to make it looking a kind of 3D... You can select it and play with `SpecialEffect` property

Comment: If you do not like it, just insert a rectangle and color its border as the background you like to be. Then, assigned a macro to it...